# Java - Inheritance issue with two children sharing a parent method

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to get my head around some inheritance concept.

Please consider the theoretical code below.
In the code below, the method GetName will return Fruit's name. 
I would like it to return Strawberry's or Apple's name.

Contrary to this issue:[Java Inheritance... Confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781852/java-inheritance-confused) the children object are of different type so the solution proposed does not apply as far as I can tell.

can you please let me know if there is a solution?

```
public class Parent{
    private Fruit aFruit = new Fruit(); // Fruit has a method getName

    public void commonProcess(){
        //Do some things Common to Child 1 and 2
       ...
        //

        System.out.println("I am a:"+ aFruit.getName());

       //Do more things Common to Child 1 and 2
       ...
        //
    }

}

public class Child1 extends Parent{
    private Strawberry aStrawb = new Strawberry(); // Strawberry extends Fruit

    public void someMethod1(){
        // Do something specific to Child2
        ...
        //
        System.out.println(commonProcess());
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent{
    private Apple anApple = new Apple();  // Apple extends Fruit

    public void someMethod2(){
        // Do something specific to Child2
        ...
        //
        System.out.println(commonProcess());
    }
}
```

When Child 1 and Child 2 will call commonProcess(), they will call the Fruit.getName method.
What I would like, is the parent method to call the method associated to the fruit in the Child class depending on who called it.
The only way I can see would be to copy commonProcess in both Child1 and Child2 and then call the local Fruit's getName but since that commonProcess method does many other things, it seems inefficient to duplicate a large piece of code.

Comment: learn what `super.` is for and when to use it.

Comment: What you appear to want to do above will happen automatically.

Comment: The whole idea behind O-O programming is that you can create Dog and Cat subclasses of the Pet class, and when you call Pet's "speak" method the Dog will go "woof" and the Cat will go "meow".